# What should we do with closed/locked questions with 1000+ votes and that are highly useful to the programmers community?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, locked-posts, historical-lock

The questions [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) and [Best Free Text Editor Supporting *More Than* 4GB Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files) don't meet today's "on-topic" standards, so I understand why they are closed.

But on the other hand, they are **highly useful question for the programmers community** (we have nearly all wanted to view 2GB+ log files at least once): 1022 upvotes and probably more if the question-upvoting was not locked (it is).

Keeping them locked is problematic because we cannot even upvote/downvote the question <strike>answers</strike>, leave a comment note about new versions of a given tool, tell about other solutions, etc.

- Deleting seems to be a bad solution, because it removes availability of very useful knowledge about resources for programmers
- Locking keeps the question/answers in a frozen state which is also not optimal

**More generally, which good solution could we find for questions 1) with a historical importance, 2) and 1000+ upvotes?**

- Proposal A: If a locked post has 1000+ upvotes, this means it's highly useful for the community. So we do an "exception to the rules", and leave it open, with a note

  *"This post does not meet the today's on-topic criteria. However since it has a long history and is considered as hugely beneficial to the community, we keep it open."*
- Proposal B: migrate it to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com? In this particular example, [Text editor or reader for working with huge files in Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/785/text-editor-or-reader-for-working-with-huge-files-in-windows) already exists, but both questions are useful on their own
- Other?

Edit: If migrating of a 1000+ votes question is complicated, we can start with the smaller question [Best Free Text Editor Supporting *More Than* 4GB Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files).

Comment: I find the current solution *relatively* good as well. *No* solution will be unproblematic, it's not clear to me why to single out the one we currently have.

Comment: Just to clarify: the question you linked is wiki-locked (which still allows voting and editing of answers), and not historical-locked. It is not "frozen".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Keeping it locked "freezes" its state at a certain point in time. So it's a very very useful question (1000+ upvotes) but it can't be modified/updated, this is a too bad, don't you think so?

Comment: @SamuelLiew Ok for editiong. But I see `Comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews` on the top of the question.

Comment: @Basj I do. Yet I also think that the alternatives aren't pure sunshine either.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The post is locked because it is asking for software recommendation which is out of topic on SO. Why is migrating it to softwarerecs.SE "not pure sunshine"? ;) What are the drawbacks to migrate it to a site precisely dedicated to software recs?

Comment: Are you a regular on SoftRecs? Are you familiarized with the site's rules and expectations for questions? Have you brought up this in their meta site? If you are/you have, please include this in this question, it could bolster the case for migration.

Comment: @yivi I have a few questions/answers there, but I wouldn't say I'm a "regular user" there. I think it is precisely the topic: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @Basj Migrations are never simple, so at the very least there is a drawback of manpower needed. Is it actually on-topic there, appropriately written, tagged, not-a-duplicate, etc? I also see a bit of a problem in just transplanting votes or similar metadata. What happens with votes from people who cannot vote over there? What happens to authors of the content – do they get the votes over there, do they remain wiki-anonymous? After we've been through all this, is it still a highly voted question? After all, the entire reason for considering migration is that there *is* a history to the Q&A.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Why is upvoting the question disabled? It is now locked forever at 1022 votes, but maybe it would be 1500 or 2000 or more now if it wasn't vote-locked?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Maybe we can start with this smaller question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files ? I can only see benefits of migrating this one to softwarerecs.SE. This one is totally frozen, no possible interaction.

Comment: @SamuelLiew For [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files), no interaction is possible: no voting, no comment (what if I wanted to say: "This tool contains malware, don't use it!", it would even be impossible!), etc.

Comment: @Basj "I can only see benefits of migrating this one to softwarerecs.SE" And do you see only benefits of *the process* of migrating it? People's time is finite, and moderators' is especially limited.

Comment: And again, you should also make the case on the _receiving_ site. Getting consensus on the [other appropriate meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) would be a good start. Then you could link the two discussions, to show how the perspectives complement each other (or not).

Comment: @yivi migration of [posts older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) has been rejected so many times I don't think that's going to fly even if code review were somehow to say yes.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok I didn't know this, this is a good point to know, thanks.

Comment: Why do we need to do something other than what we are already doing? I don't see a clear problem statement addressed... just that you want to be able to answer closed questions, which isn't worth re-visiting such a site policy for.

Comment: To put it another way, you don't go into museums and complain to the curators/staff that you should be able to wear the armor there into a modern day battle, or that you should be able to check out an ancient Egyptian scroll for reading on your next flight across country. They are items of antiquity that are valuable because of their historical significance. Old posts with historical locks on Stack Overflow are the same and should be treated the same. If something is off-topic, it's off-topic; no matter how well-received it was 10 years ago, re-opening them would be wrong.

Comment: @TylerH It was only a proposal - because I spent *hours* trying different big files viewers/editors, and the devil is in the details; I found a lack for *updated* knowledge about this, and only closed/locked questions. I *thought* it *could* have been a good fit for softwarerecs.SE, thus my meta post. Now I see 100% of people disagree, ok, I was 100% wrong :) No problem, it was just a proposal :) Not sure if comparisons with museums is really useful, I have already understood: my proposal is super bad. I should have done something else this morning than doing this proposal. End of the story :)

Comment: @Basj If you think a question is on-topic on another site, go ahead and ask it there. That a similar question exists in a locked state on SO doesn't prevent you from asking the same question on a different site if the question is in fact on-topic there. In fact, software recommendation questions being so common is the reason SoftwareRecs was created in the first place, so there would be a place for people to ask such questions somewhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Once again @TylerH, I have already understood: my proposal was bad. I should have done something else this morning than doing this proposal on meta.SO. End of the story :) There is no need to discuss it further.

Comment: I'm just trying to help provide you with a path forward since that's what your real goal is.

Comment: Wikipedia keeps [a list of text editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors), including the property ["Large file support"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Extra_features). Some questions on *Software Recommendations* are *[Text editor or reader for working with huge files in Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/785/)*, *[Linux text editor for large text files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39964)*, and *[Best viewer for large text files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/)*,

Answer (score 12):

> Keeping it locked is problematic because we cannot even
> upvote/downvote answers, leave a comment note about new versions of a
> given tool, tell about other solutions, etc.

Indeed. If it were up to me, I'd see it deleted. Option C. I am going to be as brutally honest as I can be here: This meta post is really making a mountain out of a molehill by calling this valuable. No, it's not valuable. Not anymore and not for a long time now. It's a time slice that we do not maintain and do not want to maintain, get rid of it. Google or your favourite alternative is much better at bringing you to up to date editors or viewers that can tackle huge files.

Besides... the current answer lists pretty much *all* popular and less popular but still well-known text editors. Apparently it is not so hard anymore to find an editor that can open huge files, even Notepad is on the list which is pretty satirical really. I used UltraEdit for 2gb+ XML files over 10 years ago and there were few alternatives that did not buckle under the stress at the time, but times and computers have changed. It has effectively just become a text editor listing, not a text editor which can open big files recommendation.

*Not useful.* In the slightest. Not in software recs either, there is just so little value to a list of editors just for the sake of having a list of editors. The web is full of them. But deletion of highly upvoted stuff is met with animosity so I'll settle for the current choice. Lock it up and let it be.

Comment: We *individually* cannot decide if a post is valuable or not. The community has decided it is: 1022 upvotes. Btw it will be stuck at 1022 forever because upvoting is locked. It would at least be 1023 if I could have voted, and probably 2000 or 3000 if upvoting was not locked.

Comment: @basj just because people upvoted it in the past doesn't mean it's as valuable today as it used to be. Your voting figures are speculation and we can look at the votes on this answer eventually to see whether people agree with deleting it.

Comment: @RobertLongson https://stackoverflow.com/posts/159521/timeline. It has had a 1022 score between 2008 and 2015: `1029 up and -7 down` (99.3% positive upvote ratio). Also it is 500+ favorited. So you think that, suddenly, and surprisingly, it would be very different nowadays?

Comment: @Basj Yes, time changes the usefulness of posts. New technology and solutions make old technology and solutions obsolete. That's precisely why you've asked this question, isn't it? You list that as one of the problems with locking.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok so today I learned that a 99.3% upvoted question with 1000+ votes about something that was, is, and will always be relevant in the near future for programmers (open 10 GB files without choking the editor/viewer) could suddenly become "obsolete" :) Interesting lesson... "Time changes"

Comment: @Basj you think 7 years is sudden? I think you've a different definition of sudden to almost everyone else in the computer industry.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes "sudden" because if there is a nearly-constant function `0.99 < f(t) < 0.995` for `t in [2008, 2015]`, then I would be happy to see what would the curve of `f(t)` look like to have a sudden discontinuity in its first derivative `f'(t)` to have a non-negligible decline since then... If you have evidence of this thanks to a SEDE query, feel free to share :)

Comment: @Basj my point is that nobody has any evidence because evidence for the last 7 years is entirely absent.

Comment: @RobertLongson If we all had 1 TB RAM computers nowadays, then ok *"How to open 10 GB files without choking the viewer program"* would become obsolete. Has the average RAM size of consumer-level computers changed in 7 years with a factor 10? No. Also, you have zero evidence that this question has become obsolete I think, at this point we are both losing our time, and we won't convince each other :) Have a good day, no worries, it was an interesting discussion anyway :)

Comment: How is *this* here considered as a good answer? 2nd paragraph doesn't even discuss the meta question, but is trying to answer the SO question about which editor to choose... 1st paragraph is basically *"asking recommendations about software is useless, just google instead"* - this is plain wrong, as usual the important things are in the details, and recommendations from peers with votes is valuable and better than SEO-optimized or ads from google answers. By the way, that's the main goal of "softwarerecs.SE"; and 99.3% of people voting this question considered it useful... Strange.

Comment: @Basj I don't answer anything, just highlighting what was available a long time ago and why a question like this would come into existence. I wouldn't recommend UltraEdit today. You are reading what you want to read I'm afraid. Besides you are taking this way too serious. The whole reason for my answer to exist is to get the tally. Upvotes VS downvotes. See what the majority thinks. There is no reason to go into a multi-comment tirade, just downvote.

Comment: @Gimby, maybe I overthought this :) who knows. When you suggest something on meta and get only downvotes (maybe deservedly so), it always takes some time to take a step back, I don't know if you experienced this - I'll forget about this and move on :)

Comment: @Basj just another thing. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/14193797) question has a score of 467, and it will get my upvote too, not because it's useful, but because it's fun as hell :)